# Android: How can I create a layout within a layout ?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app I want to have a button that if the user clicks it
than a new layout is opened within the current (acually the main) layout.
the new layout should not fill all of the screen and parts of the previous layout 
should be grayed out.
Any ideas on how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show a hidden layout within your button's onClick event by calling

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

You can also fade out view elements or whole views with

```
view.setAlpha(75); 
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
```

Note that "view" in the first example is your layout element.. LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc.  and in the 2nd example, "view" is the element(s) you're trying to gray out.

Comment: When a view is not visible does it require space on the screen (and the user just see it as empty space) or can I put for example text there and once I make the view visible than it covers the text ?
also, I can use views with their id's (for example : R.layout.main is an int) how can I get the view that this id is representing ? 

thanks for the help!

Comment: You can set 3 types of visibility to a view - visible, invisible & gone.  Invisible is not visible but still takes up space and gone is invisible and takes up not space.  To hide text once your layout becomes visible, simply call setVisibility on the TextView object.

Comment: I tried doing it but "view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);"
causes a runtime error and there is no "setAlpha" method defined on view (double checked by looking at the view API)...

Answer (score 0):

Follow the answer of SBerg413. And for more information. you can take the relativelayout for the part that you want to hide and display on the button click.
And as like SBerg413 answer. you can hide the respective layout and show the layout you want to display.
Hope it will help you.
Thanks.

Comment: I tried doing it and I have two problems :
1.the defines VISIBLE,INVISIBLE,GONE are not recognized (I had to use the value it self for now)
2.when I press the BACK butten I want it to hide the new buttens that became visible, but it exits the app.
thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a ViewFlipper to achieve what you want, position the viewflipper where the child views should fit (part of the screen you say)..

Inflate the rest of the "child" layouts from other xml, add them to the flipper and switch between them when you want...